# apprequest dialog from facebook action script 3 sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-actionscript-api

I am writing an application for Android with Adobe AIR + using facebook action script 3 SDK.
Can I show standart apprequest dialog to user on Android phone?

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: 'You should learn more about this awesome game.', data: 'tracking information for the user'});
```

How can I call it from facebook action script 3 SDK? Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

take a look of this script, that answer you question

> How can I call it from facebook action script 3 SDK?

```
private function inviteFriends():void
{
    var dat:Object = new Object();
    dat.message = "Let's invite friends for our Super Extra Max Facebook App, more info go to http://blog.ukasz.com";
    dat.title   = 'Super Extra Max Facebook App';
    // filtering for non app users only
    dat.filters = ['app_non_users'];
    //You can use these two options for diasplaying friends invitation window 'iframe' 'popup'
    Facebook.ui('apprequests', dat, onUICallback, 'popup');
}
```

and this is the handler

```
private function onUICallback(result:Object):void{
    if(result == null){
         trace('User closed the pop up window without inviting any friends');
         return
    }
    var invitedUsers:Array  = new Array();
    invitedUsers = result.request_ids as Array;
    trace('You Have Invited ', invitedUsers.length,' friends');
    //Simple if else if you want user to invite certain amount of friends
    if(invitedUsers.length > 1){
        trace('GREAT, USER IS GENERATING TRAFFIC');
    }else{
        trace('No Good, User invited only one friend.');
    }
}
```

[Thanks to Lucas](http://blog.ukasz.com/facebook-invite-friends-from-flash-as3-how-to-stimulate-traffic/)

Comment: This works for desctop version, but for mobiles I use FacebookMobile class.